# Best way to display series of matplotlib plots in browser

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am still familiarizing myself with the library and am interested in displaying a series of figures in a webpage or saving them to a format that I can then save and output to a webpage. What would be the best way to do this?

```
        plots = []
            for row in dataFrame:
                x-values = row[1] #Series of x values
                y-values = row[2] #Series of y values
                a = plt.figure()
                plt.plot(x-values, y-values)
                plots.append(a)

        #Display array of plots in a browser
```

Comment: There are lots of frameworks which will do complicated versions of this. A simple version is to have a static HTML file that links to images `row1.png, row2.png, ... rowN.png` and then save each plot (instead of `plots.append()`) with the row-appropriate name.  If your users are going to be local (or mostly you) you might like the IPython Notebook.